# how to divide text file by empty line

Tags: python

I would like loop over text file with poker hands which are divided by empty line.
Text file look like this:

> PokerStars Hand #172075855663:  Hold'em No Limit ($0.50/$1.00 USD) -
>   2017/06/22 0:34:27 CET [2017/06/21 18:34:27 ET] Table 'Parysatis'
>   6-max Seat #6 is the button Seat 1: AndrVik89 ($114.27 in chips)  Seat
>   2: bumpandrun5 ($112.66 in chips)  Seat 3: steelNike ($100 in chips) 
>   Seat 4: Johnii141 ($105.20 in chips)  Seat 5: PapaGun5286 ($194.78 in
>   chips)  Seat 6: VexVictor ($180.95 in chips)  AndrVik89: posts small
>   blind $0.50 bumpandrun5: posts big blind $1
>   *** HOLE CARDS**  Dealt to Johnii141 [Qd Kd] steelNike: folds  Johnii141: raises $1.80 to $2.80 PapaGun5286: folds  VexVictor: folds 
>   AndrVik89: folds  bumpandrun5: folds  Uncalled bet ($1.80) returned to
>   Johnii141 Johnii141 collected $2.50 from pot Johnii141: doesn't show
>   hand 
>    **SUMMARY *** Total pot $2.50 | Rake $0  Seat 1: AndrVik89 (small blind) folded before Flop Seat 2: bumpandrun5 (big blind) folded
>   before Flop Seat 3: steelNike folded before Flop (didn't bet) Seat 4:
>   Johnii141 collected ($2.50) Seat 5: PapaGun5286 folded before Flop
>   (didn't bet) Seat 6: VexVictor (button) folded before Flop (didn't
>   bet)
>
> PokerStars Hand #172076017834:  Hold'em No Limit ($0.50/$1.00 USD) -
>   2017/06/22 0:38:49 CET [2017/06/21 18:38:49 ET] Table 'Parysatis'
>   6-max Seat #5 is the button Seat 1: AndrVik89 ($122.85 in chips)  Seat
>   2: bumpandrun5 ($141.38 in chips)  Seat 4: Johnii141 ($102.20 in
>   chips)  Seat 5: PapaGun5286 ($166.14 in chips)  Seat 6: VexVictor
>   ($171.45 in chips)  VexVictor: posts small blind $0.50 AndrVik89:
>   posts big blind $1 l xFlake l: sits out 
>   *** HOLE CARDS**  Dealt to Johnii141 [9h Ks] bumpandrun5: calls $1 Johnii141: folds  PapaGun5286: raises $3.15 to $4.15 VexVictor: folds 
>   AndrVik89: folds  bumpandrun5: calls $3.15
>    **FLOP**  [2h 3d Jd] bumpandrun5: bets $4.66 PapaGun5286: calls $4.66
>    **TURN**  [2h 3d Jd] [5h] bumpandrun5: bets $9.08 PapaGun5286: calls $9.08
>    **RIVER**  [2h 3d Jd 5h] [2s] bumpandrun5: checks  PapaGun5286: bets $10 bumpandrun5: folds  Uncalled bet ($10) returned to
>   PapaGun5286 PapaGun5286 collected $35.42 from pot PapaGun5286: doesn't
>   show hand 
>    **SUMMARY *** Total pot $37.28 | Rake $1.86  Board [2h 3d Jd 5h 2s] Seat 1: AndrVik89 (big blind) folded before Flop Seat 2: bumpandrun5
>   folded on the River Seat 4: Johnii141 folded before Flop (didn't bet)
>   Seat 5: PapaGun5286 (button) collected ($35.42) Seat 6: VexVictor
>   (small blind) folded before Flop

After *** SUMMARY ***  - Flop (didn't bet) we have another poker hand.

What i wanna do is get all information i need from the first hand and go to  next hand and get same information. Hands are divided by empty line.
Then put it to the dataframe.

What i have done already:

```
file = open(r'C:\Users\AdamPer\Desktop\Magisterka\2rece.txt','r')
linia = [i.rstrip('\n') for i in file]

import re

pattern_hand = re.compile(r'#(\d+):')
pattern_sb = re.compile('\$(\d+.\d+)/')
pattern_table = re.compile('(Table)\s\'(\w+)(\')')
pattern_seat = re.compile('Seat\s(\d):')
Hand_id = []
sb = [] 
table = []
nr_of_player = []                        
for i in range(len(linia)):
    matches_hand = pattern_hand.finditer(linia[i])
    for match_hand in matches_hand:
        Hand_id.append(match_hand.group(1))
    matches_sb = pattern_sb.finditer(linia[i])
    for match_sb in matches_sb:
        sb.append(match_sb.group(1))
    matches_table = pattern_table.finditer(linia[i])
    for match_table in matches_table:
        table.append(match_table.group(2))
    matches_nr_of_player = pattern_seat.finditer(linia[i])
    for match_nr_of_player in matches_nr_of_player:
        nr_of_player.append(match_nr_of_player.group(1))

print(Hand_id)
print(sb)
print(table)
print(nr_of_player)
```

nr_of_player list is bad. What i need is to check how many seats are taken by players between those lines and store it as number.
line: 'Table 'Parysatis' 6-max Seat #6 is the button'
and
line: 'AndrVik89: posts small blind $0.50'

My target is to get Dataframe [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFSLH.png)
I have thousands of text file like this.

Comment: Are the lines really wrapped like that?

Comment: You can use `contents.split('\n\n')` to split a string at blank lines.

Comment: Is the contents of "PokerStars Hand #..." all in one line? Contents being from "Hold'em No Limit" to "Flop"

Comment: "Are the lines really wrapped like that?" 
It's look like this when i load them into python by first two lines: 
https://prnt.sc/mdwi0q